# Live search from multiple input

Tags: jquery

My goal is to hide elements that that doesn't match the input from multiple `<input>`. I can do this if it's just one input but it resets when i switch to another input. I have done this using the `keyup` or `input` event of jQuery. But my problem is when there are multiple inputs (particularly text, checkboxes and radios). Is there a plugin or framework or even the manual way to do this?

[Example UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RvAm0.jpg) for better understanding.

JavaScript

```
$('#search').on('input', function () {
    var card = $('[data-dorm]');
    for (i = 0; i < card.length; i++) {
      if (!(card[i].dataset.dorm.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.value.toLowerCase()) > -1) && !(card[i].classList.toString().indexOf('hide') > -1)) {
        $('#'+card[i].id).hide();
      } else if (this.value === '') {
        $('#'+card[i].id).show();
      }
    }
  });
```

I have similar code for the `data-price`

HTML

```
<a href="Dorm_Content.html" class="col s6 m4 l3 xl2" id="d1" data-dorm="SLU Dormitory" data-price="3000">
      <div class="card waves-effect waves-block">
        <div class="card-image">
          <img src="http://materializecss.com/images/sample-1.jpg">
          <span class="card-title">SLU Dormitory</span>
        </div>
        <div class="card-content p-1">
          <i class="fas fa-wifi"></i>
          <i class="fas fa-shower"></i>
          <i class="fas fa-utensils"></i>
          <span class="right">PHP 3000</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>
```

For example, I have this cards here and I want the other cards to hide when it doesn't match the data-dorm and/or price.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In order for us to help you better, can you please update your question so that it shows your **existing code** and details any failed [**attempts made so far**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), along with clearly stating what your desired **result** is. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Answer (score 0):

[JQuery quicksearch](https://github.com/riklomas/quicksearch) does this pretty nicely, and can be applied on various html elements (example divs with images) easily.

Some small examples I've done with it before:

- Table row filtering: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ddan/tqhxqwrh/)

```js
$('input#id_search').quicksearch('table#table_example tbody tr');
```

- Calendar items: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ddan/tu88y3cm/)

```js
$('#quicksearch').quicksearch('#calendar a.fc-event');
```

If you share some of your HTML and JS we can probably easily show an example of what you want to implement.